# changing link url using .htacces

Tags: .htaccess, url, hyperlink

This is the link **http://djmobi.in/?dir=/Mobile_Ringtones&p=1&sort=1/Mobile_Ringtones.html**

Please tell me how to remove **?dir=**  from the above link I want to make it look like below link eg.

**http://www.finewap.com/Category/9497/Mobile_Ringtones.html**

Comment: Have you read about [`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)?

Answer (score 0):

You must not think the way "How to remove `?dir=`", but "Which link use instead of this complex one".

This is the kinf of `.htaccess` you'll need :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule   ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)\.html$    index.php?dir=$1 [L]
```

This `.htaccess` will redirect each url like http://www.domain.com/foo.html to http://www.domain.com/index.php?dir=foo (this will be transparent)

This is a good start, I let you search for some documentation to add your pages and sort management (we don't have enought datas to give you a working piece of code)

Comment: **I Have Tried a lot but it does not work. following is my index.php file code**
**i have removed index.php from index.php?dir=**
**it is just now ?dir=**
**My link for example: http://www.djmobi.in/?category=/Full_Mp3_Songs&p=1&sort=1/Full_Mp3_Songs.html**


i have full code file here [my index.php code][1]


and my htaccess file here [my .htaccess file code][2]


  [1]: http://djmobi.in/code.txt
  [2]: http://djmobi.in/htaccess.txt